How to multimap list that has comma separated values as elements
Assume a list that has comma separated element:
x = ["FOO,BAR", "BAZ"]
How can someone map the above list to:
["FOO", "BAZ"]
["BAR", "BAZ"]


What should be the output if the input is ["FOO,BAR", "BAZ", "QUX,FUM"]?

Are you just printing the two lists? What if the input is ["FOO", "BAR,BAZ"]

You should be able to do this by splitting each element and then taking the Cartesian product -
import itertools

x = ["FOO,BAR", "BAZ"]
total = []
for a in x:
    total.append(a.split(','))
print(list(itertools.product(*total)))


total = [a.split(",") for a in x] would be more concise and Pythonic.

This creates a single list of tuples. Clearly not what is required

It would be rather simple to convert those tuples into lists (which is a simple cast)

Answering the question literally and making no assumption about the actual requirement, it's as simple as:
x, y = ["FOO,BAR", "BAZ"]

for t in x.split(","):
    print(str([t, y]).replace("'", '"'))

Output:
["FOO", "BAZ"]
["BAR", "BAZ"]

